# Why I cannot access host files from inside kubernetes pod? "permission denied" error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-security

I would like to test a security vulnerability (attack scenario) in K8s cluster. As a privileged K8s user, I want to mount `~/.kube` directory inside a pod in order to change/read K8s configurations and CA info. Or maybe any root directory on Master-node. The pod runs with no error, and I can tell that the directory has already been mounted to the pod, but I cannot read the mounted directory.
Here is the deployment file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: attack-pod
  namespace: target-ns
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 1001
    fsGroup: 0
    fsGroupChangePolicy: "OnRootMismatch"

  tolerations:
  - key: "is_control"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "true"
    effect: "NoExecute"
  nodeName: master-node-1

  imagePullSecrets:        
  - name: regcred    

  containers:
  - name: attack-container
    image: bash
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 1h" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /home/admin-user/.kube
      name: mount-root-into-mnt
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true

  volumes:
    - name: mount-root-into-mnt
      hostPath: 
        path: /home/admin-user/.kube

  serviceAccountName: service-account
```

But when I exec into the pod `kubectl -n target-ns -it attack-pod -- bash` and try to list the files inside `/home/admin-user/.kube` I get this error:

`ls: can't open '.': Permission denied`!

Although, the directory was mounted successfully, and I added the correct permissions in `securityContext`.

Comment: Are you running on a system with some sort of mandatory access control system like selinux or apparmor?

Comment: Can you check permissions it was mounted with?

Comment: @larsks I'm not totally sure, But I'm using the user-admin who has root access and the owner of `.kube` file. Is there a way to check this access control?

Comment: @kool The permission of `.kube` is `drwxr-x---` and the directory is owned by `admin-user`,

Comment: As `admin-user` I can read/write on `.kube` with no issues directly on the system.  However, I cannot access them from inside the pod.

Comment: @MoAlkhodary on what OS you are using ?